# MySQL - Max,min, avg & daily data at same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL database. The data I'm using is here- [Sales_history](https://www.dropbox.com/s/whrer73w5izv6u9/SALES.csv?dl=0). I'm looking to extract the maximum & average of the values of the data in table (Not max & avg per day. It's the avg & max of the whole set of data) & at the same time print the data per day too.

I'd like the output to look as below

[image]

The query I've written up so far is

```
SELECT 
SALES_DATE,
NUM_SALES,
MIN(NUM_SALES) AS MIIN,
MAX(NUM_SALES) AS MAAX,
TRUNCATE(AVG(NUM_SALES),2) AS AVVG
FROM SALES_HISTORY
GROUP BY
SALES_DATE
```

This obviously groups `MAX`, `MIN` & `AVG` per day which is not what I want. Could I please get help to achieve this?

Comment: Why is the date the same every row but not the aggregates?

Comment: @HartCO -- this would be a lot easier if `mysql` supported `analytic functions`.  Basically if I understand correctly the query should return all records in the `sales_history` table, but also show aggregated information.  Multiple subqueries is perhaps the easiest solution with `mysql`...

Comment: @sgeddes Ah, I think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the aggregation in a subquery since MySQL doesn't support analytic/window functions:

```
SELECT a.SALES_DATE
      ,a.NUM_SALES
      ,b.MIIN
      ,b.MAAX
      ,b.AVVG
FROM SALES_HISTORY a
JOIN (SELECT SALES_DATE
            ,MIN(NUM_SALES) AS MIIN
            ,MAX(NUM_SALES) AS MAAX
            ,TRUNCATE(AVG(NUM_SALES),2) AS AVVG
      FROM SALES_HISTORY 
      GROUP BY SALES_DATE
      ) b
   ON a.SALES_DATE = b.SALES_DATE
```

If the Max/Min are wanted for the entire period, not by date, we can just use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.SALES_DATE
      ,a.NUM_SALES
      ,b.MIIN
      ,b.MAAX
      ,b.AVVG
FROM SALES_HISTORY a
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT MIN(NUM_SALES) AS MIIN
                   ,MAX(NUM_SALES) AS MAAX
                   ,TRUNCATE(AVG(NUM_SALES),2) AS AVVG
             FROM SALES_HISTORY 
            ) b
```

Comment: Thank you Hart. The `GROUP BY` in the inner join isn't needed as it gives incorrect  result. If you could update the answer by removing it, I'll accept he solution as the answer please.

Comment: @usert4jju7 If we're including a non-aggregate like `SALES_DATE` along with aggregates, then we should need to `GROUP BY` the same, most RDBMS won't even allow it without the `GROUP BY`.  Are the results incorrect with the `GROUP BY`? That'd be curious to me.

Comment: I totally understand what you're saying. However, including the `group by` means it won't give me the actual max & min ( The result returned by `select max(num_sales)). Once, I remove group by, it does. Strange indeed.

Comment: @usert4jju7 Oh, so you don't actually want the max/min per day, but for all days combined?  Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much Hart. I'll need both the queries at different places.